# Iteratively get the max of a data frame column, add one and repeat for all rows in r

Tags: sql, r, mapping

I need to perform a database operation where I'll be adding new data to an existing table and then assigning the new rows a unique id.  I'm asking about this in R so I can get the logic straight before I attempt to rewrite it in sql or pyspark.

Imagine that I've already added the new data to the existing data.  Here's a simplified version of what it might look like:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(id = c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA),
             descriptions = c("dodgers", "yankees","giants", "orioles", "mets"))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
     id descriptions
  <dbl> <chr>       
1     1 dodgers     
2     2 yankees     
3     3 giants      
4    NA orioles     
5    NA mets
```

What I want is:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     id descriptions
  <dbl> <chr>       
1     1 dodgers     
2     2 yankees     
3     3 giants      
4     4 orioles     
5     5 mets
```

An I can't use `arrange` with `rowid_to_columns` id's be deleted.

To get a unique id for the `NA` rows while not changing the existing ones, I want to get the max of the id column, add one, replace NA with that value and then move to the next row.  My instinct was to do something like this: `df %>% mutate(new_id = max(id, na.rm = TRUE) + 1)` but that only get's the max plus one, not a new max for each row.  I feel like I could do this with a mapping function but what I've tried returns a result identical to the input dataframe:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(id = ifelse(is.na(id),
                     map_dbl(id, ~max(.) + 1, na.rm = FALSE),
                     id))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
     id descriptions
  <dbl> <chr>       
1     1 dodgers     
2     2 yankees     
3     3 giants      
4    NA orioles     
5    NA mets
```

Thanks in advance--now if someone can help me directly in sql, that's also a plus!

Comment: What is the issue with the solution I provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method where we add the `max` value with the cumulative sum of logical vector based on the NA values and `coalesce` with the original column 'id'

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
   mutate(id =  coalesce(id, max(id, na.rm = TRUE) + cumsum(is.na(id))))
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     id descriptions
  <dbl> <chr>       
1     1 dodgers     
2     2 yankees     
3     3 giants      
4     4 orioles     
5     5 mets
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL option, using `sqldf` for demo:

```r
sqldf::sqldf("
  with cte as (
    select max(id) as maxid from df
  )
  select cte.maxid + row_number() over () as id, df.descriptions
  from df
    left join cte where df.id is null
  union
  select * from df where id is not null")
#   id descriptions
# 1  1      dodgers
# 2  2      yankees
# 3  3       giants
# 4  4      orioles
# 5  5         mets
```

Comment: Didn't you say *"help me directly in sql"*? I interpreted SQL as the preferred solution ...

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Window function row_number() requires window to be ordered, please add ORDER BY clause. For example SELECT row_number()(value_expr) OVER (PARTITION BY window_partition ORDER BY window_ordering) from table;`

Comment: Try changing it to `cte.maxid + row_number() over (order by id) as id`. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: This is with spark

Comment: Right, sorry, you said that earlier. I checked a few random sources, and while I couldn't find if `order by` is *required*, all of the examples using `row_number()` include `order by`, so perhaps that's the key. I hope this works ... and I'm not a spark expert.

Comment: So when I try to apply this to my actual table (which is slightly more complicated) I'm getting unexpected results.  I'll post a new question just for sql about it.